# How to have a computed property that has a getter and a default setter?

Tags: swift

This doesn't work.
[image]

Nor does this
[image]

And this doesn't work because now the property has no setter.
[image]

How do i keep the custom getter and set the value without any computations?

Comment: Please post code as code blocks, and not images. Also, read up on _computed_ (not stored!) properties in [Swift Language Guide - Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

Comment: Computed variables do not have a backing store. Create a `private var _currentTrack` instance var. in the setter set `_currentTrack = newValue` and in the getter return it.

Comment: HAS...that's the answer...why didn't you post it as such?

Comment: dfri...we lose context...in this case compiler feedback if i post the three lines of code...pictures make more sense here.

Comment: @Aaronium112 Pictures bring more negative than positive with them. It's fine to post them in addition to the code, but pictures alone are not usually sufficient, because you cannot copy-paste code to do corrections. To Stack Overflow and search engines, pictures are non-searchable, so the information is harder to find on the internet. Because of that problem, pictures could turn your question or answer into a "downvote magnet", or even get your question put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

First, here is how to <s>solve</s> work around this issue:

```
// THIS IS BAD, DO NOT DO IT LIKE THAT:
private var _currTrack : MPMediaItem?
var currentTrack : MPMediaItem? {
    get { return playlist?.items[index] }
    set { _currTrack = newValue }
}
```

Now why you should *not* use this hack: the getter and the setter of the same property should agree, in the sense that once you set it to an `X`, getter should normally give you `X` back. Your approach does not do that.

A better solution would be to look for the index of `newValue` among playlist items, and setting the `index` if a matching value is found:

```
var currentTrack : MPMediaItem? {
    get {
        return playlist?.items[index]
    }
    set {
        if let tmp = playlist?.items.indexOf(newValue) {
            index = tmp
        }
    }
}
```